# How to connect to Mongo using Robomongo

Tags: mongodb

Is there some sort of trick to connecting to Mongo using Robomongo?

I have a Python application using the connection string:

```
mongodb://myuser:mypassword@127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin
```

which is able to connect to my local Mongo service perfectly.

However, when I open Robomongo and create a connection setting and use:

```
Connection tab:
    address=127.0.0.1
    port=27017
Authentication tab:
    Perform authentication: checked
    Database: admin
    User Name: myuser
    Password: mypassword
```

and test the connection, it reports that it can connect to 127.0.0.1, but authentication fails. What setting am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was using Robomongo 0.8 with Mongo 3.4, which Robomongo 0.8 doesn't support.